# UINavigationController Navigation Bar Image is hiding other backbuttons and custom images?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

```
- (UINavigationController *)navigationController {

nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                               initWithRootViewController:[self demoController]];

UIImage *image;

// If Iphone/iPod Touch
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    // If iPhone 5 or new iPod Touch
    if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568){
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav.png"];
    } else{
        // Regular iPhone
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav.png"];

    }
}

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

[nav.navigationBar addSubview:imageView];

return nav;

}
```

As I try to add **leftBarButtonItem** as

```
  - (UIBarButtonItem *)leftMenuBarButtonItem {

UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];

[backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"main_menu.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIBarButtonItem *barBackButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: backButton];

[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(leftSideMenuButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

return barBackButtonItem;

 }
```

It doesn't display main_menu.png on navigation, but if comment this code

```
      // [nav.navigationBar addSubview:imageView];
```

it will show main_menu.png, what is issue, why nav.png is now showing other images, it is added as SubView, so what should I do to display others left or right bar button items, over nav.png.

Answer (score 0):

Yo shouldn't be adding the image to an image view and adding that as a subviews. Instead you should be calling `setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:` or using the appearance delegate to set the background image for the navigation bar.

Comment: I did it, but it changed the color of status bar, on very top